# What is the difference between "I buy them in town" and "I buy them from town"

Tags: expressions

I was reading a story and I ran into this sentence:

> I buy them in town.

I thought it was an error. I think the correct way of saying it is:

> I buy them from town.

Am I right? If not, please explain to me what the difference is between the two sentences.

Comment: Why repost here when the answer you have is already correct?

Comment: Alternatives: "I bring them from town." (The buying is implicit ) "I get them from town." ("In" works here, too.)

Comment: @modulusshift **bring** does not assume **buying** only **carrying** or **conveyance**. "I get them **in** town", or "I get them **from** the grocer" would be used by a native speaker

Comment: @Peter The OP hasn't moved the question. The question was migrated. The answer is also not fully correct. The respondent jigged the question in favour of their interpretation by removing the article from *in the town* and keeping it in *from the town*.

Comment: @Peter The OP hasn't moved the question themselves. The question was migrated from ELU by the folks over there. The answer is also not fully correct. The respondent has craftily  jigged the question in favour of their interpretation by removing the article from "in the town" and keeping it in "from the town".

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks for your explanation, I think your edit of the OP's question **from the town** -> **from town** makes more sense as the basis of the question. The original post was **in town**, **from *the* town** and I've found it sometimes challenging to keep the **intent** of a learner's question unchanged while editting since they may be asking more than they realise, as most **learning minds** will do (hope this is not off topic).

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I agree! Just to explain  my edit, the Original was actually "in **the** town" and "from **the** town", but the respondent's first edit only changed the first to "in town", and left "from **the** town" as it was. My edit was just to make them symmetrical :)

Comment: @Peter I am a native speaker. I know they sound a little weird, but think about them in the past tense. "Yeah, I brought them from town." "I got them in town." The present tense works as well, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

***I buy them in town*** (no article) means you travel (on foot, by car, by train, on horseback) to town in order to buy *them* (whatever *they* happen to be).

***I buy them from the town*** means you have an agreement with the town's administration that has control over *them* (whoever or whatever *they* happen to be) and sells them to you now and then.

Answer (score 1):

Your question of **in** and **from** is related to the intent of the verb you are using.  Both are **grammatically correct**, however one **does not make sense**.

One does not **buy** something **directly from** a **geographic entity**, one buys things

> **at**
>   **in**
>   **around**
>   **on the way to**

a place.  One

> **carries**
>   **brings**
>   **comes**
>   **goes**

**from** a geographic location.

> I buy them **in** town.

Means you acquired *something* while **at a town**

> I buy them **from** town

does not make sense. In fact if you wrote

> I **bought** it **from** town.

a native speaker would probably think you meant

> I **brought** it **from** town.